# Getting Adware/Malware popup on Chromium

Tags: chromium, malware

For the past few days I'm getting a pop up from www.adultcameras.info in the Chromium browser on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't recall installing any new software or extension in Chromium.

I even uninstalled and reinstalled Chromium using terminal - it still persists.

Adding, 0.0.0.0 www.adultcameras.info in `/etc/hosts`i s also not being able to block it.

I am going nuts with this.. as it is showing mature content and is quite disturbing in office :/

*Can anyone help me with this?*

Solution: The problem was solved by changing the DNS settings to google public DNS

Comment: how about using [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)? :P

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, post it as an answer and mark it as the "Best Answer."

Answer (score 5):

1. In Chromium scroll down to the **Privacy** header and click on the big **Content settings** button.

   [image]

   Scroll down a little bit more in the window that appears until you see the **Pop-ups** section. The option *Do not allow any site to show pop-ups* should be selected; if it isn’t select it. Click the **Done** button at the bottom of the window.

   [image]

   In later versions of Chromium the above navigation is similar but changed a bit to 3 vertical dots icon in upper right corner **⋮** -> *Settings* -> scroll down to *Advanced* -> *Privacy and security* -> *Content settings* -> *Popups* -> *Blocked (recommended)*.
2. AdBlock is the most popular Chrome extension, with over 40 million users. AdBlock blocks ads all over the web. AdBlock is also included by default in the QupZilla web browser from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: tried every damn thing.. and still it is coming.. some pop ups from rdsrv.com ... I have even reinstalled chrome.. removed all extension rest everything... still it is coming... desperately need some help

Comment: Normally , chrome syncs   extensions/plugins when you log in to chrome account using gmail.. May be that is the case to reinfect

Answer (score 1):

Find out its temp folders in the system and remove them all. View [this page](http://www.removeviruspro.com/how-to-remove-pop-up-ads-browser-redirect-from-google-chrome/) for suggested actions to remove pop-ups on the web browser. I really get much from that.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling chromium will not do anything as it is installed in your chromium profile in your home.

In chromium, in Settings, enable Advanced settings, and choose Reset Settings.

This should do it.

If not, and unless you find out what exact files need to be removed, you can take the radical action to remove your `~/.config/chromium` folder but you will lose every configuration made to chromium

But if you have enabled global sync, your configuration will be restored from google cloud, so you will back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove adware extension.

Go to settings/extensions, and remove the culprit. It should be pretty easy to find. For me, it was named "adware", and since the only other extension I have installed is chromecast, it was a no-brainer.

In my case, my kids installed it from a flash games website. Linux is pretty much immune to garden-variety malware, but apparently chrome browser extensions are too easy to install.