# Visiting fake popup on Ubuntu

Tags: trojan

I visited a fake popup website twice by mistake. Will this infect my Ubuntu system with any Trojan or AdWare? I'm afraid. I visited it yesterday and it asked for username and password. I rejected it and closed off that tab. Today, when I turned on my system, I had problems with logging in. I typed the correct password but Ubuntu said it was incorrect. I had to reset the password with recovery mode and delete old keyring logins and login to keyring with new password. Can I know why this is happening? Is it happening because I removed the CD drive from my computer to see if it was damaged and booted without the CD Drive? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Using Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 32bit.

Comment: If I have to install any anti-virus software, do please notify.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/583749/getting-adware-malware-popup-on-chromium

Comment: @Takkat It doesn't continiously come up. **I** visited it by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, but Ubuntu is no less vulnerable to for instance security holes in Chrome than Windows is. The difference is that there is less malware available for Ubuntu.

Fake browser extensions, that does not rely on native code, would probably run equally well on Ubuntu. So a good tip is to check your browsers list of extensions, and see if you notice anything unusual, like high cpu use.

Comment: I found nothing unusual. All extensions were using 0% CPU. I am using Chromium 62.

Comment: I am using the following extensions: UBlock Origin, Google Docs Offline, Boomerang for Gmail, Google Dictionary and VirusTotal Scanning utility.

Comment: Then the answer is probably that nothing bad happened. It takes a vulnerability in the browser to end up with malware from merely visiting a page. Chrome/Chromium is reasonably quick at patching.